# SSRS child group position

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have situation where I need to place subcategory (child group) in my matrix in SSRS report but I have to make it not adjacent to parent. 
To be exact I need to list all facilities and their KPIs and also all their lines and lines' KPIs in one matrix. Something similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pv1d.jpg

I don't have much experience with SSRS reports, but know it should be possible since I had seen report with this done

Answer (score 0):

Create a new report for every child group and use it as sub report in master report